# XML and restrictions with complexType

Tags: xml

Schema for my xample

```
<xsd:element name="Subject" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Name of the subject. Values are: Vaje, Kolokvij, Predavanje, Izpit</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Vaje"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Kolokvik"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Predavanje"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Izpit"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Professor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Name of the professors</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attribute name="prof" type="Professors"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and i also have Professors as restriction that you can not insert anything else

```
<xsd:element name="Professors">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attribute name="id"/>
<xsd:attribute name="name"/>
<xsd:attribute name="surname"/>
<xsd:attribute name="code"/>
<xsd:attribute name="email"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

but i always get here `<xsd:attribute name="prof" type="Professors"/>` this error

```
'Professors' must refer to an existing simple or complex type.
```

What i want? XML looks like this:

```
<Professors id="1" name="sss" surname="sss" code="15426" email="sss@sss.si"/>
<Professors id="2" name="fff" surname="ff" code="15446" email="ff@ff.si"/>
```

and then in later i wat to use that number 1 from id

```
<Subject>vaje</Subject>
<Professor>1</Professor>
```

How can i create schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Professor" element has no attributes it can be defined as:

```
<xsd:element name="Professor" type="xsd:int"/>
```

It does not need to have an inner attribute.  To restrict the value of the Professor element to one of the defined professors, you need to use a key and keyref:

```
<!-- The root element of the instance document -->
<xsd:element name="Root">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <!-- Subject ref and definition omitted for brevity -->
        <xsd:element ref="Professors" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Professor" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="ProfessorId"> 
        <xsd:selector xpath="Professors"/> 
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="ProfessorIdRef" refer="ProfessorId"> 
       <xsd:selector xpath="Professor"/> 
       <xsd:field xpath="text()"/> 
    </xsd:keyref>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Professors">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="id"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="name"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="surname"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="code"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="email"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Professor" type="xsd:string"/>
```